# VBA Lookup by Multiple Criteria - Then Copy & Paste

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2003, code

Currently I have a 2 way database with 10+ fields and 1,000+ rows. Some fields are customer name, car model, year of model, price, date of purchase.

I would like to lookup rows of data by multiple criteria (i.e. looking up car sales by customer name, car purchased, and date) and then have the relevant rows copy and pasted from the data worksheet to the output macro output worksheet.

I need to lookup the rows of data by multiple criteria and some searches will return multiple rows that match the criteria.

I want to be able to push a button on the macro output worksheet allowing me to enter in customer name, car model, and date and then have the macro copy and paste the row(s) from the data worksheet to the macro output worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Excel Table feature, and not create a macro.

I would convert the "database" from a range to an Excel Table (Select range, Insert Ribbon / Table).

Then I would use the Filter buttons that will appear next to each column heading to filter the data as required.  Multiple criteria can be used and it will show all matching rows.